# how to fetch the single record in mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an experience in php & mysql.In MYSQL Using the query.
`*" SELECT * from Tablename" *`
fetch e all the records from the table.

`*" SELECT * from Tablename" *`

Comment: Do you want to fetch all of the documents (per your SQL comparison) or a single one (per the title of the question)? If the latter, how are you choosing the document that you want? Have you had a chance to look at 'Getting Started' guides for MongoDB's PHP driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB/Driver/Manager for this like below

```
    <?php $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->insert(['x' => 1]);
$bulk->insert(['x' => 2]);
$bulk->insert(['x' => 3]);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.collection', $bulk);

$filter = ['x' => ['$gt' => 1]];
$options = [
    'projection' => ['_id' => 0],
    'sort' => ['x' => -1],
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('db.collection', $query);

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}

?>
```